# Creating users in django (NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.last_login)

Tags: django, django-users

I'm coding a web app with django and now I'm starting to handle users.
I'm trying to do the easy part, just create a new user throught admin interface, but when I try to do it I get a error and I don't find any info about it.

I enter django admin, log in with superuser, go to users, add user.
It only asks for: username and password.
When I submit changes then I get a NOT NULL constraint failed, this:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.last_login
```

I revised django documentation, and there it says to create a user like this:

- from django.contrib.auth.models import User
- user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

So, I open a terminal, and do "./manage.py shell" "import django" "import User" and then I try this code, but fails too, it says:

```
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Maybe I've changed something in the first part of the project? I've created models, templates, urls and used /static/ for references to files.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`last_login` field changed [in django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#abstractuser-last-login-allows-null-values). Just run the migrations

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: And, don't do "import User" in the shell.
Import it exactly as documentation says:
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, you saved me a bunch of time. Wish I looked this up earlier. However for me I also had to run `python manage.py makemigrations` before doing that command

Answer (score 3):

Same issue, Had to run `python manage.py migrate --fake` and then `python manage.py migrate` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got a same error. But in my html file, i pass a wrong name...

Answer (score -1):

In the app folder there is migration folder.. remove all files from it just keep **pycache** folder and **init**.py 
then execute python manage.py migrate and then python manage.py makemigrations ..
simply we are removing the older migrations and migrating them again